# How do you change the color of specified pixels in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I want to be able to detect a certain area of pixels based on their RGB values and change them to some other color (not black/white).

I have tried changing these values in the code, but my resulting images always show black pixels replacing the specified locations:
`pixelMap[i,j]= (255,255,255)`

```
from PIL import Image
im  = Image.open('Bird.jpg')
pixelMap = im.load()

img = Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
pixelsNew  = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        toup = pixelMap[i,j]
        if(int(toup[0]>175) and int(toup[1]<100 and int(toup[2])<100) ):
             pixelMap[i,j]= (255,255,255)
        else:
             pixelsNew[i,j] = pixelMap[i,j]
img.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You will find that iterating over images with Python loops is really slow and should get in the habit of using Numpy or optimised OpenCV or skimage code.

So, starting with this image:

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('bird.jpg')

# Make into Numpy array
imnp = np.array(im)

# Make all reddish pixels white
imnp[(imnp[:,:,0]>170) & (imnp[:,:,1]<100) & (imnp[:,:,2]<100)] = [255,255,255] 

 # Convert back to PIL and save
Image.fromarray(imnp).save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am getting an error with the example you gave. It states, "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous." Do you know what I should to do get around this?

Comment: @SajidKhan Did you use my exact code (by copy and paste) and exact same image? What version of PIL/Numpy and what OS do you use? Also please click `edit` under your question and add the full error stack. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a tiny bug:

Instead of:  `pixelMap[i,j]= (255,255,255)`
Use: `pixelsNew[i,j] = (255,255,255)`